# Unappending elements from divs and appending them to where they were originally appended?

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to add a 'minimize' button to my popups in my web app. When popups appear they are appended to the body. When I hit minimize I'd like them to be appended to a transparent div at the bottom of the page, so minimized popups appear side by side as inline-block elements and not stacked on top of each other. When I hit the minimize button again, I'd like to remove the popup from the transparent div at the bottom of the page and append it back to the body.

```
<body>
<div class="le-popup"/>
<div class="le-minimized-popup-container">
</body>
```

Click the minimize button on the div called "le-popup" and it should be appended to the div called "le-minimized-popup-container". Click the minimizebutton on the collapsed form of the popup inside "le-minimized-popup-container", and it is removed from "le-minimized-popup-container" and appended back to the body.

I know there's jQuery functions like .remove() and .detach(). The latter of which I think returns without destroying the element on which the method is used. But I can't seem to find a way to append something to the node it was appended to before it was appended to something else. Make sense?

Thx
-- Gaweyne.

EDIT:

```
var $leMinimizeButton = $('<div class="minimize"/>').append($lePopup).click(_.bind(function(){
   $lePopup.toggleClass('minimize'); // Adds a class which collapses the body of the popup, giving it a minimized appearance and moves it to the bottom of the page.
}, this))
```

Is all I have so far. Problem with this is the popups just stack on top of each other this way. Would like to do what I explainded above.

Comment: Got some JS/jQuery to show as well?

Comment: Sure I can do that... Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) should already do what you want. From the documentation:

> You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another:
>
> ```
> $( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );
> ```
>
> If an element selected this way
>   is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be
>   moved into the target (not cloned)

[`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) also follows this philosophy. So if I understood your question correctly, you can make the following change:

```
var $leMinimizeButton = $('<div class="minimize"/>').append($lePopup).click(_.bind(function(){
   if ($lePopup.hasClass("minimize")) {
       $lePopup.removeClass('minimize')
               .appendTo(".le-popup");
   }
   else {
       $lePopup.addClass('minimize')
               .appendTo(".le-minimized-popup-container");
   }
}, this))
```

Comment: The problem with this is when you click the minimize button again (now, of course, working as a maximize button) it is still appended to the minized-popup-container div. It hasn't been unappended and placed back where it was, that is, as a child of the body tag.

Comment: @Gaweyne I think I understand now. I modified my answer. If it is still incorrect, I may not be understanding something correctly. If that's the case, could you provide [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/) of how it currently works?

Comment: That looks right. It didn't occur to me to write a conditional testing for the class minimize. Will give it try. One sec :o